# How to make a dropdown-menu with small image?

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

### Details

- I want to add a little flag to left of my dropdown menu
- I am not sure what is the best practice for that.

### Here is what I've tried

```
<!-- Dropdown-Menu -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 drop-down ">
        Select Country : 
        <select id="state" onchange="window.location=this.value" >
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <?php 
            foreach(array_unique($countries) as $country){ ?>
            <option value="#<?php echo $country ; ?> ">
            <img 
            src="/img/flags_3/flags/48/
            <?php echo isset( $distributor['hq_country']['name'] ) ? $distributor['hq_country']['name'] : '' ?>.png" 

            width="16px" height="16px">
            <?php echo $country ; ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>  
        </select>
    </div>
```

her is a [link](http://codepen.io/evoque2015/pen/vEgwPg) to what I have now

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it's not possible to add images inside a `<select>`

Your best option would be to use a `<ul>` with `<li>` elements and build something that function's like a select but built with other elements

something along the lines of

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="your image here" />some test here</li> 
    <!-- or use css or a font icon for cleaner mark up -->
</ul>
```

Then bind some mouse events with javascript

Comment: I am open to suggestions - if you have any. I just want to get that done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a containing class around your select, you could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
select,
option {
    width: 200px;}

div:before {
    content: '';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background-image: url('yourImageHere.png');}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w1bfvfft/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jquery UI:

> http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

This is what you need :)