# How to populate a dropdown list in ascending order in PHP?

Tags: php

### Details

- I want to populate a dropdown-menu of my county list in ascending order
- A-Z

### What I've tried

Here is how I grab my countries array

```
<?php 

    if(is_array($distributors)) {

        foreach ($distributors as $k => $v)
        {
            $continents[$k] = $v['distributor']['continent_id'];
            $countries[$k] = $v['hq_country']['name'];
        }
        array_multisort( 

            $continents, SORT_ASC, 
            $countries, SORT_ASC, 

            $distributors);
    }

?>
```

Here is how I populate my dropdown menu

```
<!-- Dropdown-Menu : Country Names  -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 drop-down ">
        Select Country : 
        <select id="state" onchange="window.location=this.value" >
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <?php 
            foreach(array_unique($countries) as $country){ ?>
            <option value="#<?php echo $country ; ?> ">

            <?php echo $country ; ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>  
        </select>
    </div>
```

### Here is my result

[image]

Want to see my list live ? [HERE](http://codepen.io/evoque2015/pen/bNgPaO)

Comment: So you posted another question earlier and similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/27905395/ and decided to post a new one, because of?

Comment: @Fred-ii- : This is totally separate logic from the other one. Here I want to know how to sort my list ...

Comment: So, why didn't you wait and put both aspects/logic of the questions into one, rather than posting two seperate questions?

Comment: I just think that it deserve to be in a diff post. I want it that way. I want to organize my profile to have a question with 1 accept answer that solve 1 logic. Why can't I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, just comment out `$continents, SORT_ASC,` - It should work.

```
<?php 

    if(is_array($distributors)) {

        foreach ($distributors as $k => $v)
        {
            $continents[$k] = $v['distributor']['continent_id'];
            $countries[$k] = $v['hq_country']['name'];
        }
        array_multisort( 

            // $continents, SORT_ASC, 
            $countries, SORT_ASC, 

            $distributors);
    }

?>
```